# magento 2.3.2 captcha for checkout not showing in admin settings

Tags: magento2, checkout, guest-checkout, recaptcha

I am using magento 2.3.2 and I am trying to set google recaptha on checkout page.
In google search i get this option as below picture but this option not found in my magento2 version. How can I add google recaptcha for all type for checkout.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The option is no longer available in the code. I searched for the whole code under vendor directory. https://belvg.com/blog/how-to-enable-captcha-in-magento-2.html create your own or use any third-party plugin.

```
<captcha>
            <frontend>
                <areas>
                    ...
                </areas>
            </frontend>
        </captcha>
```